# Cannot read property 'amounts' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to search through an API to get the results of each specific address. The problem I am facing is it returns the error "Cannot read property 'amounts' of undefined". I tried to prevent it with an if statement however it still goes down the API until no result is found and errors out.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx6vcuo1/21/)

```
var _miner = 't1PFzdktgbdtmApkCFFkg8dCPvfXrJ2DwPm'; 
var _coin = 'xxx';
var explorerTX = 'asdf';

//Payment history
$.ajax({
  url: "https://xxxxxx.net/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var addr = _miner;

    //Payment History List
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      var payments = data[i].payments;
      for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {

        //console.log(payments[j].amounts[addr]);
        if (payments[j].amounts[addr]) {

          //Time
          //console.log(payments[j].time);
          var date = payments[j].time;
          var date = new Date(parseInt(date));
          var date = date.toGMTString();

          //blocks
          var block = [];
          var blocks = payments[j].blocks;
          for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
            //console.log(blocks[b])
            block.push(blocks[b]);
          }

          //txid
          var txid = payments[j].txid;

          //amount
          var amount = payments[j].amounts[addr].toFixed(8);

        }
      }
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Try changing range of `j` from `[0, 200)` to `[0, data[i].payments.length)`. Meaning, change the loop to `for (var j = 0; j < data[i].payments.length; j++) {}`

Comment: You have to check if `payments[j]` is defined not `payments[j].amounts[addr]`. Why not use `j < payments.length` as the loop's condition ?

Comment: I only want to return 200, thats why I do not do the entire length @Titus

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the object with the `amounts` on it is `undefined`. In your case that would be `payments[j]`. It would be helpful to console.log the value of `payments[j]` inside of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check

```
(addr in payments[j].amounts)
```